# Replace every element of an array in a string with preg_replace() only once, without replacing text which already got replaced

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, preg-replace

I need to have a function which converts specific words in text into links, so I use `preg_replace()`. However, I don't know how to skip words that have already been converted into links.

Here's the code:

```
function highlightWords($content)
{
    $arr = array("php", "and sql", "sql");

    foreach ($arr as $key=>$value)
    {
        $content = preg_replace("/\b(".preg_quote($value).")\b/i", '<a href="#">\1</a>', $content, 1);
    }

    return $content;

}

echo highlightWords("This text will highlight PHP and SQL and sql but not PHPRO or MySQL or sqlite");
```

The function should make 3 separate links total - "php", "and sql", "sql". Unfortunately, the result looks like this:

```
This text will highlight <a href="#">PHP</a> <a href="#">and <a href="#">SQL</a></a> and sql but not PHPRO or MySQL or sqlite
```

How do I "tell" the function not to process words that are between "a" tags?

P.S. Words in array MUST be ordered RANDOMLY, do not suggest me to re-order an array. I need to modify preg_replace

Comment: `$arr = array("php", "sql", "and sql");`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with a working solution. I know how to re-order words in array, but they need to be ordered randomly; therefore, my question was how to modify the FUNCTION, and NOT the array

Comment: Why must they be ordered randomly, can't you just sort the array before applying the regex?

Comment: words are ordered not entirely randomly, but they are ordered by other key ($arr is an array with many sub-arrays in live website, I only simplified my example here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookarounds to ensure that you don't replace something which is already in an a tag, e.g.

```
/(?!<a href=\"#\".*)\b(".preg_quote($value).")\b(?!.*<\/a>)/i
```

- `(?!<a href=\"#\".*)` simply checks that there can't by an a opening tag in front  of your search word
- `(?!.*<\/a>)` makes sure that there isn't an a closing tag after your search term

Comment: Words MUST be ordered RANDOMLY in the array. Well, in fact, they are ordered not entirely randomly, but they are ordered by other key ($arr is an array with many sub-arrays in live website, I only simplified my example here)

Comment: @MindaugasLi I forgot, you don't need to sort the array, since `preg_replace()` does that for you, so it starts with the longest search. Just do it in one go and you are good to go.

Comment: This one works, but not as expected. I need to replace each word only once (that's why I added "1" to preg_replace function). If this example is used, it replaces all occurrences. If I add "1" to the preg_replace in your example, only single word in whole text is replaced.

Comment: yes, that's right (the array contains only unique words), and each word needs to be replaced only once (no matter how many times this word is repeated in text)

Comment: @MindaugasLi updated my answer, just replace the regex and use lookarounds to make sure you don't replace something which is in a tags.

Comment: This is it - EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you for another great answer.